# Powerbuilder New column added in grid datawindow not displaying in excel

Tags: grid, powerbuilder

I am using 12.5 version recently added new col to table and using it in grid dw. It's displaying on window when I execute app but in saveas excel it's not displaying that col. I tried adding it at last and middle also but no luck. Tried many things but no luck...any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the SQL behind a datawindow object never updates the dwo.  You have to manually add any new column to it.  In your case it sounds like you did this but you need to make sure.  Also does the column have data?  Is the same dwo used to display the data also the basis for the saveas to excel?